# Rails validates only incremental value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Is there an Active Record Validation to verify if the record to be added is bigger or equals than any other record already in the Database? I am thinking in something like:

```
class Reading < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :register
  validates :kwh, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: "any kwh in database"}
end
```

If there is no such method to do it that way, the use of **validates_with**:

```
class Reading < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :register
  validates_with IncrementalValidator
end

class IncrementalValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    @reading = Reading.order("created_at").last
    if record < @reading
      record.errors[:base] << "This recored is not incremental"
    end
  end
end
```

Is my best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a custom validator:

```rb
class Reading < ApplicationRecord
  validates :kwh, presence: true
  validate :validate_kwh_is_the_greatest

  def validate_kwh_is_the_greatest
    # stop validation if kwh is NULL or no record exists with greater value
    return if kwh.nil? || !self.class.where(self.class.arel_table[:kwh].gteq(kwh)).exists?

    errors.add :kwh, "kwh must be greater than the one stored in existing records"
  end
end
```

A short explanation:

Using Arel table as following...

```rb
self.class.where(self.class.arel_table[:kwh].gteq(42)).exists?
# Reading.where(Reading.arel_table[:kwh].gteq(42)).exists?
```

...is similar to write:

```rb
self.class.where('readings.kwh >= ?', 42).exists?
# Reading.where('readings.kwh >= ?', 42).exists?
```